# Handle non-serializable values on React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am creating a reducer for a user account that looks like this

```
export class Account {
    id: number;
    user: User;

    constructor(id: number, user: User) {
        this.id = id;
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Then I need a user:

```
export class User {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    token: string;

    constructor(name: string, email: string, token: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.token = token;
    }
}
```

So I create an state like this:

```
interface AccountState {
    id: string;
    user?: User;
}
```

The thing is when I update the state like this:

```
const accountSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'account',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setAccount(state, action) {
            state.id = action.payload.id;
            state.user = new User(action.payload.name action.payload.email, action.payload.token)
        },
    }
})
```

I am getting an error
A non-serializable value was detected in the state, in the path: `account.user`. Value: {"email": undefined, "name": undefined, "token": undefined}

I could create an state with all user values inside instead of user?: User, and I see there is a link that says I can use non-serializable values but it's not reccomended, https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state

So my question is, what's the best way to handle this case? I am thinking on create a `userSlice` and update its state from `accountSlice` but I am not sure if this is the correct approach and I cannot find a similar example on the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you should use a plain object instead of a class:

```
export type User = {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    token: string;
}

const accountSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'account',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setAccount(state, action) {
            const { id, name, email, token } = action.payload;
            state.id = id;
            state.user = { name, email, token }
        },
    }
})
```

Classes have non-serializable functions and other boilerplate that as you mention is discouraged in Redux.